# Android hold button for few seconds and then do something

Tags: java, android

I want to make button which does something when is hold for 3 seconds and I got this. It does work but I wonder if its correct way of doing things, what I mean by that that I want to make all buttons designed same way, whole menu based on hold for **x** seconds and then proceed with something and I wonder if it wont make problems and wont make my app laggy.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    onbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.onbutton);
    onbutton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private Handler handler;
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            switch(motionEvent.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    onbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.onbuttonshape);
                    handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(run,3000);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    onbutton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonshape);
                    handler.removeCallbacks(run);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        Runnable run = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "delayed msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: Why not simply use `setOnLongClickListener()` ? Does it have to be exactly 3 seconds?

Comment: I think this belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 4):

Don't reinvent the wheel 
Android has a

```
setOnLongClickListener()
```

That you can subscribe to and so detect that **long press** that you are looking for..

The doc is [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html)

Comment: I believe the idea was to be able to modify and set the actual duration of the press. The above does not allow for that. Let me know if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

I would just use the method `setOnLongClickListener()`:

```
button.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        // Do what you want to do atfer a long click here
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: How do you set a 3 second duration for this? I'm not sure you can.